# About getContentLength method of HttpUrlConnection of java in a Android Program

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I can download .apk and other executable files, unless I try to do it over the Corporate WiFi.  This is a matrix of my results.

[image]

When I don't explicitly set any properties for the URL connection (using `setRequestProperty()`) then `getContentLength()` returns the correct length.

However, because the program is doing a multi-threaded download, I have to use set the Range property with `setRequestProperty`, as follows:

```
Range: bytes = 0 - TotalBytes / TheadNum  //first thread
Range: bytes = TotalBytes/ThreadNum - TotalBytes / TheadNum * 2  //second thread, and etc
```

When I do that, I get erroneous results one in four cases in the above form.

> ```
>    threadNum          = 2
>    totalFileSize      = 39058483
>    getContentLength() = 171 // (expected correct value is 17217690)
> ```

Comment: Does my last edit with the table look correct or should I change something?

Comment: So in the failure situation, are you saying that is when you get bad content length one out of every four times (approximately)? Or does that always happen.  Is it your own multithreaded download client code that's giving you trouble? Is it possible that Chrome works because you have specified a proxy.pac script or wpad script or a direct http proxy so it works inside the corporate network (behind firewall), but the multithreaded client doesn't have that?  I don't understand what the Range issue has to do with the corporate WiFi.

Comment: Yes,the download result form you last edited is what I want to expression,but,the erroneous results are only occur one in four cases in the above form .it isn't occurs the 25% times of my client run times,and now u have changed those  by  better symbols.

Comment: I think I get ur mind, chrome is alway doing some proxy for all users, but my client doesn't have any proxy tools, I code my client only setted the Range property in HTTP headers and connect by **HttpUrlConnection**.I don't know the fail case how it happend. Is that direct Internet Connection ,its server have setted some proxy work ,so that my client could work?

Comment: Range issue don't need to do something with corporate wifi,  I just have to connect corporate wifi in my work.

Comment: First thing I would do is read about Chrome and the kinds of proxy configurations it supports, typically there is one of: 0. No proxy, 1. Static IP of proxy, 2 proxy PAC script (makes choices decides of where to redirect each user request), or 3. WPAD which is another type of flexible redirection scheme. You can just look at your Chrome configuration and see if a proxy is configured and how.  If there's no proxy involved then it's a waste of time to pursue it in your code. Take it in steps.

Comment: I am just guessing, and asking questions. I've got very little in-depth experience with the specific details of the technologies you're dealing with, so someone else will have to help you or you'll have to keep digging.

Comment: `Range: bytes = 0 - TotalBytes / TheadNum` is not correct. That means the first thread will download the entire file, the 2nd thread the first 1/2 of it, the 3rd thread the first 1/3 of it, etc. You should also be aware that *N* parallel downloads are not going to be *N* times as fast as one.

Comment: okay, I've editted it to explicit expression.